# Filter Reverse Pairing in Query

Tags: sql, join, hql

I am attempting to write a HIVE query that returns a.user_id and b.user_id count of movies they both prefer. When I run the query I get a.user_id, b.user_id, count, and set of movies. I also get b.user_id, a.user_id, count, and set of movies.

My question is how do I limit my query to only a.user_id,b.user_id count, and set of movies.

I have already attempted a proposed solution in [Remove reverse duplicates from an SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13041802/remove-reverse-duplicates-from-an-sql-query) by chaning line 4 to `ON(a.movie_id = b.movie_id AND a.user_id < b.user_id)`

```
SELECT a.user_id, b.user_id, count(*) AS num, collect_set(m.movie_title)
FROM ratings a
JOIN ratings b
ON (a.movie_id = b.movie_id)
JOIN movies m
ON (a.movie_id = m.movie_id AND b.movie_id = m.movie_id)
WHERE (a.user_id <> b.user_id)
GROUP BY a.user_id, b.user_id;
ORDER BY num DESC;
```

Current Output:

A, B, 25, list of movies

B, A, 25, list of movies

Desired Output:

A, B, 25 list of movies

Comment: And why doesn't the proposed solution work?

Comment: I think it is because I am doing a self join and when you change the where statement it while start joining user_id on itself. For example the file size was 172.9kb and altering it caused the file size to become 17.8MB. When I checked the output the number of matching films went from a range of 6-138 and now they are at a magnitude of 300,000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect the query you want to be:

```
SELECT a.user_id, b.user_id, count(*) AS num, collect_set(m.movie_title)
FROM ratings a JOIN
     ratings b
     ON a.movie_id = b.movie_id JOIN
     movies m
     ON a.movie_id = m.movie_id
WHERE a.user_id < b.user_id
GROUP BY a.user_id, b.user_id
ORDER BY num DESC;
```

Comment: I am wondering if also removing the AND statement caused it stop looping. Thank you. By the way there is an extra semicolon on the second to last line.

Comment: @BennyBaysinger . . . Hmmm.  Remotely possible.  The original `join` condition is redundant, so it doesn't affect the result set.  It could affect the query plan, though.

Comment: I just tried both with and without the 'AND'. Same exact query as you would expect. I swore I tried your proposed solution and the previous poster's solution. I even tagged the question with the same solution. I must of had another typo. Anyway works perfectly hopefully it will help someone else with the same issue.