# MS Access Match groups of rows in structure table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an interesting problem to overcome with a table.  I have stored a simplified set of data from our full parts database (which we are not at liberty to hack around in, and does not perform the required queries).  I need to find where engineers have created completely cloned assemblies including their position in space (xyz position and xyz rotation) and area. I basically need to list them out for removal in the main system.  The table shows the top level assembly, and it's first level children.

i.e.

Assembly_1
 |- Part_1 (0,0,0 0,0,0)
 |- Part_2 (0,0,0 0,0,0)
 |- Part_3 (0,0,0 0,0,0)

Assembly_2
 |- Part_1 (0,0,0 0,0,0)
 |- Part_2 (0,0,0 0,0,0)
 |- Part_3 (0,0,0 0,0,0)

Assembly_3
 |- Part_1 (500,0,0 0,0,0)
 |- Part_2 (500,0,0 0,0,0)
 |- Part_3 (500,0,0 0,0,0)

Assembly_4
 |- Part_4 (0,0,0 0,0,0)
 |- Part_5 (0,0,0 0,0,0)
 |- Part_6 (0,0,0 0,0,0)

Stored in one table as:

```
Parent ID  |  Child ID  | Assembly Level | Area | Position
Assembly_1 | Assembly_1 | 0              | 0001 | 0,0,0 0,0,0
Assembly_1 | Part_1     | 1              | 0001 | 0,0,0 0,0,0
Assembly_1 | Part_2     | 1              | 0001 | 0,0,0 0,0,0
Assembly_1 | Part_3     | 1              | 0001 | 0,0,0 0,0,0
Assembly_2 | Assembly_2 | 0              | 0001 | 0,0,0 0,0,0
Assembly_2 | Part_1     | 1              | 0001 | 0,0,0 0,0,0
Assembly_2 | Part_2     | 1              | 0001 | 0,0,0 0,0,0
Assembly_2 | Part_3     | 1              | 0001 | 0,0,0 0,0,0
Assembly_3 | Assembly_3 | 0              | 0001 | 0,0,0 0,0,0
Assembly_3 | Part_1     | 1              | 0001 | 500,0,0 0,0,0
Assembly_3 | Part_2     | 1              | 0001 | 500,0,0 0,0,0
Assembly_3 | Part_3     | 1              | 0001 | 500,0,0 0,0,0
Assembly_4 | Assembly_4 | 0              | 0002 | 0,0,0 0,0,0
Assembly_4 | Part_4     | 1              | 0002 | 0,0,0 0,0,0
Assembly_4 | Part_5     | 1              | 0002 | 0,0,0 0,0,0
Assembly_4 | Part_6     | 1              | 0002 | 0,0,0 0,0,0
```

In the example I would expect Assemblies 1 & 2 to be displayed, but not Assembly 3, as although it uses the same parts, it's x,y,z position is different, and not Assembly 4 as it uses different parts and is in a different area.

What I would like is to extract is something like:

```
 Assembly  | Cloned Assembly | Area
Assembly_1 |    Assembly_2   | 0001
```

And I don't mind if you end up with additional lines where Assembly 1 & 2 swap sides. Even this is far more palatable than searching the whole structure manually!

I suspect at the moment this might well end up being a VBA solution (chiefly as I understand VBA far more than I understand SQL!) as I can't even get close to this in SQL, however that is time consuming (I believe there is in excess of 20000 line items to search and compare in the full dataset with nearly 400 areas in a product), and this will be repeated per product of which there are about 30+.

I have tried following examples to extract duplicates (which has in fact worked brilliantly to extract where an assembly at level 0 have been accidentally repeated into the product), but this is where one single line matches another line, not where a group of several lines match another group.

Any help / guidance or even just the affirmation of use of VBA would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATED SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   a1.GROUP,
   a1.SUB_GROUP,
   a1.ParentID AS Assembly,
   (SELECT DISTINCT AssemblyTable.NAME
      FROM AssemblyTable
      WHERE AssemblyTable.ChildID=a1.ParentID) AS NAME,
   (SELECT DISTINCT AssemblyTable.OWNER
      FROM AssemblyTable
      WHERE AssemblyTable.ChildID=a1.ParentID) AS OWNER,
   a1.Area,
   (SELECT DISTINCT AssemblyTable.ITEM_CREATION
      FROM AssemblyTable
      WHERE AssemblyTable.ChildID=a1.ParentID) AS ITEM_CREATION,
   a2.ParentID AS CLONED_ASSEMBLY,
   (SELECT DISTINCT AssemblyTable.NAME
      FROM AssemblyTable
      WHERE AssemblyTable.ChildID=a2.ParentID) AS CLONE_NAME,
   (SELECT DISTINCT AssemblyTable.OWNER
      FROM AssemblyTable
      WHERE AssemblyTable.ChildID=a2.ParentID) AS CLONE_OWNER,
   (SELECT DISTINCT AssemblyTable.ITEM_CREATION
      FROM AssemblyTable
      WHERE AssemblyTable.ChildID=a2.ParentID) AS CLONE_CREATION
FROM (SELECT * FROM AssemblyTable ORDER BY AssemblyTable.ITEM_CREATION ASC) AS a1
   INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM AssemblyTable ORDER BY AssemblyTable.ITEM_CREATION ASC) AS a2
      ON (a1.ParentID < a2.ParentID)
      AND (a1.Area = a2.Area)
      AND (a1.[Position] = a2.[Position])
      AND (a1.ChildID=a2.ChildID)
WHERE a1.ParentID<>a2.ParentID
ORDER BY a1.GROUP, a1.SUB_GROUP, a1.Area, a1.ParentID;
```

Table is now:

```
Parent ID  |  Child ID  |      Name       | OWNER  | Assembly Level | Area |   Position    | ITEM_CREATION
Assembly_1 | Assembly_1 | Assembly_1_Name | User_1 | 0              | 0001 | 0,0,0 0,0,0   |  01-01-2016  
Assembly_1 | Part_1     | Part_1_Name     | User_1 | 1              | 0001 | 0,0,0 0,0,0   |  01-01-2016  
Assembly_1 | Part_2     | Part_2_Name     | User_1 | 1              | 0001 | 0,0,0 0,0,0   |  01-01-2016  
Assembly_1 | Part_3     | Part_3_Name     | User_1 | 1              | 0001 | 0,0,0 0,0,0   |  01-01-2016  
Assembly_2 | Assembly_2 | Assembly_2_Name | User_2 | 0              | 0001 | 0,0,0 0,0,0   |  01-01-2017  
Assembly_2 | Part_1     | Part_1_Name     | User_2 | 1              | 0001 | 0,0,0 0,0,0   |  01-01-2017  
Assembly_2 | Part_2     | Part_2_Name     | User_2 | 1              | 0001 | 0,0,0 0,0,0   |  01-01-2017  
Assembly_2 | Part_3     | Part_3_Name     | User_2 | 1              | 0001 | 0,0,0 0,0,0   |  01-01-2017  
Assembly_3 | Assembly_3 | Assembly_3_Name | User_3 | 0              | 0001 | 0,0,0 0,0,0   |  01-01-2016  
Assembly_3 | Part_1     | Part_1_Name     | User_3 | 1              | 0001 | 500,0,0 0,0,0 |  01-01-2016  
Assembly_3 | Part_2     | Part_2_Name     | User_3 | 1              | 0001 | 500,0,0 0,0,0 |  01-01-2016  
Assembly_3 | Part_3     | Part_3_Name     | User_3 | 1              | 0001 | 500,0,0 0,0,0 |  01-01-2016  
Assembly_4 | Assembly_4 | Assembly_4_Name | User_4 | 0              | 0002 | 0,0,0 0,0,0   |  01-01-2016  
Assembly_4 | Part_4     | Part_4_Name     | User_4 | 1              | 0002 | 0,0,0 0,0,0   |  01-01-2016  
Assembly_4 | Part_5     | Part_5_Name     | User_4 | 1              | 0002 | 0,0,0 0,0,0   | 01-01-2016  
Assembly_4 | Part_6     | Part_6_Name     | User_4 | 1              | 0002 | 0,0,0 0,0,0   | 01-01-2016
```

I am occasionally still seeing:

```
 Assembly  | Cloned Assembly | Area
Assembly_2 |    Assembly_1   | 0001
```

Comment: VBA is going to be your friend here.  You could try to flatten the file so you can do compares in SQL... but that could turn into a nightmare.  (Especially if you can have a variable amount of parts per assembly instead of just 3 per assembly as in your example.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a [self join](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-self-joins.htm) where you join the same table to itself. Make the join criteria on the needed matched columns and then filter for different *ParentID*. And to avoid the [reverse duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13041802/remove-reverse-duplicates-from-an-sql-query) use a special `ON` clause with greater/less than equality:

[image: Self Join SQL Diagram]

```
SELECT DISTINCT a1.ParentID AS Assembly, a2.ParentID AS ClonedAssembly, a1.Area
FROM AssemblyTable AS a1 
INNER JOIN AssemblyTable AS a2 
    ON (a1.ParentID < a2.ParentID) AND (a1.Area = a2.Area) 
    AND (a1.[Position] = a2.[Position]) AND (a1.ChildID = a2.ChildID)
WHERE a1.ParentID <> a2.ParentID;

-- Assembly    Cloned_Assembly  Area
-- Assembly_1       Assembly_2  0001
```

Comment: Wow...........Thank you so much for that!  I can't believe it was a relatively simple a query in the end!  I had been dreading the idea of going through all of our assemblies using loops and VBA, you are a hero!

Comment: The ON clause by the way does not seem to be removing the effect of getting Assembly_1 in both the Assembly, and cloned assembly columns with the same matching assembly in the other column, however, as this has produced a far shorted list than I had to work with originally, my comments above still stand, and the gratitude remains thank you!.  Maybe a little VBA to spin down the already shortened list isn't such a big thing now.

Comment: Apologies, forget the last comment, I'd accidentally hit Design View instead of table, so MS Access had screwed up the query!  Re-applied the correct query and all is well and good with the world!

Comment: I realise that it's been a while, and I've amended the SQL to add more information in, however I'm getting a strange issues I wondered if you could help with when rolling this out on larger data sets:  1.  The left hand Assembly is not always the earliest created version, despite me putting in **ORDER BY AssemblyTable .ITEM_CREATION_DATE ASC** and changing the **INNER JOIN AssemblyTable AS a2** to **INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM AssemblyTable  ORDER BY AssemblyTable .ITEM_CREATION_DATE ASC) AS a2** to try to force the table to be in the correct order?!

Comment: 2.  Where I get multiple matches, i.e Assembly_1 to Assembly_2 and Assembly_3, I then also get a line showing Assembly_2 to Assembly_3 as a clone, absolutely correct, but unnecessary as it is captured by the first group.  Currently working on a query of this query to try to strip those out, i.e. **WHERE NOT IN** clause.  I can't include the new SQL query in the comments as it's too big!

Comment: @Rob ... please ask a new question even referencing this older one.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, apologies, new question posted [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44797102/ms-access-match-groups-of-rows-in-structure-table-part-2] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44797102/ms-access-match-groups-of-rows-in-structure-table-part-2)

Answer (score 0):

You will definitely be better off using VBA, however some stored queries could help you speed up the comparison process. I would create a query that has the following: Assembly ID, Count(ChildID), Min(Child ID), Sum(Position+Rotation over the entire assembly).

That will very quickly eliminate the majority of "not exact clone" possibilities, leaving very few ones to check part by part.