# MS Access Match groups of rows in structure table Part 2

Tags: sql, ms-access

This is a follow on from:
[MS Access Match groups of rows in structure table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41763666/ms-access-match-groups-of-rows-in-structure-table)

My data table is as follows:

```
GROUP   | SUB_GROUP  |  ParentID  |   ChildID  |      Name       | OWNER  | Assembly_Level | Area |   Position    | ITEM_CREATION
GROUP_1 | SubGroup_1 | Assembly_1 | Assembly_1 | Assembly_1_Name | User_1 | 0              | 0001 | 0,0,0 0,0,0   |  01-01-2016  
GROUP_1 | SubGroup_1 | Assembly_1 | Part_1     | Part_1_Name     | User_1 | 1              | 0001 | 0,0,0 0,0,0   |  01-01-2016  
GROUP_1 | SubGroup_1 | Assembly_1 | Part_2     | Part_2_Name     | User_1 | 1              | 0001 | 0,0,0 0,0,0   |  01-01-2016  
GROUP_1 | SubGroup_1 | Assembly_1 | Part_3     | Part_3_Name     | User_1 | 1              | 0001 | 0,0,0 0,0,0   |  01-01-2016  
GROUP_1 | SubGroup_1 | Assembly_2 | Assembly_2 | Assembly_2_Name | User_2 | 0              | 0001 | 0,0,0 0,0,0   |  01-01-2017  
GROUP_1 | SubGroup_1 | Assembly_2 | Part_1     | Part_1_Name     | User_2 | 1              | 0001 | 0,0,0 0,0,0   |  01-01-2017  
GROUP_1 | SubGroup_1 | Assembly_2 | Part_2     | Part_2_Name     | User_2 | 1              | 0001 | 0,0,0 0,0,0   |  01-01-2017  
GROUP_1 | SubGroup_1 | Assembly_2 | Part_3     | Part_3_Name     | User_2 | 1              | 0001 | 0,0,0 0,0,0   |  01-01-2017  
GROUP_1 | SubGroup_1 | Assembly_3 | Assembly_3 | Assembly_3_Name | User_3 | 0              | 0001 | 0,0,0 0,0,0   |  01-01-2016  
GROUP_1 | SubGroup_1 | Assembly_3 | Part_1     | Part_1_Name     | User_3 | 1              | 0001 | 500,0,0 0,0,0 |  01-01-2016  
GROUP_1 | SubGroup_1 | Assembly_3 | Part_2     | Part_2_Name     | User_3 | 1              | 0001 | 500,0,0 0,0,0 |  01-01-2016  
GROUP_1 | SubGroup_1 | Assembly_3 | Part_3     | Part_3_Name     | User_3 | 1              | 0001 | 500,0,0 0,0,0 |  01-01-2016  
GROUP_1 | SubGroup_1 | Assembly_4 | Assembly_4 | Assembly_4_Name | User_4 | 0              | 0002 | 0,0,0 0,0,0   |  01-01-2016  
GROUP_1 | SubGroup_1 | Assembly_4 | Part_4     | Part_4_Name     | User_4 | 1              | 0002 | 0,0,0 0,0,0   |  01-01-2016  
GROUP_1 | SubGroup_1 | Assembly_4 | Part_5     | Part_5_Name     | User_4 | 1              | 0002 | 0,0,0 0,0,0   |  01-01-2016  
GROUP_1 | SubGroup_1 | Assembly_4 | Part_6     | Part_6_Name     | User_4 | 1              | 0002 | 0,0,0 0,0,0   |  01-01-2016
```

And the query I got to with the help of parfait:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   a1.GROUP,
   a1.SUB_GROUP,
   a1.ParentID AS Assembly,
   (SELECT DISTINCT AssemblyTable.NAME
      FROM AssemblyTable
      WHERE AssemblyTable.ChildID=a1.ParentID) AS NAME,
   (SELECT DISTINCT AssemblyTable.OWNER
      FROM AssemblyTable
      WHERE AssemblyTable.ChildID=a1.ParentID) AS OWNER,
   a1.Area,
   (SELECT DISTINCT AssemblyTable.ITEM_CREATION
      FROM AssemblyTable
      WHERE AssemblyTable.ChildID=a1.ParentID) AS ITEM_CREATION,
   a2.ParentID AS CLONED_ASSEMBLY,
   (SELECT DISTINCT AssemblyTable.NAME
      FROM AssemblyTable
      WHERE AssemblyTable.ChildID=a2.ParentID) AS CLONE_NAME,
   (SELECT DISTINCT AssemblyTable.OWNER
      FROM AssemblyTable
      WHERE AssemblyTable.ChildID=a2.ParentID) AS CLONE_OWNER,
   (SELECT DISTINCT AssemblyTable.ITEM_CREATION
      FROM AssemblyTable
      WHERE AssemblyTable.ChildID=a2.ParentID) AS CLONE_CREATION
FROM (SELECT * FROM AssemblyTable ORDER BY AssemblyTable.ITEM_CREATION ASC) AS a1
   INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM AssemblyTable ORDER BY AssemblyTable.ITEM_CREATION ASC) AS a2
      ON (a1.ParentID < a2.ParentID)
      AND (a1.Area = a2.Area)
      AND (a1.[Position] = a2.[Position])
      AND (a1.ChildID=a2.ChildID)
WHERE a1.ParentID<>a2.ParentID
ORDER BY a1.GROUP, a1.SUB_GROUP, a1.Area, a1.ParentID;
```

I am occasionally seeing the following output:

```
 Assembly  | Cloned Assembly | Area
Assembly_2 |    Assembly_1   | 0001
```

Where Assembly_1 is created before Assembly_2, but displays after it, despite my ordering the data before, after and during the joins and displaying of results?!  Any ideas on how I can force the left hand Assembly column to be the earliest created item?

Also, another issue I'd like to resolve, and something which has only come to light with larger data sets is that when you get multiple matches, the matched Assemblies then also show on the list, i.e.:

```
 Assembly  | Cloned Assembly | Area
Assembly_2 |    Assembly_1   | 0001
Assembly_2 |    Assembly_6   | 0001
Assembly_1 |    Assembly_6   | 0001
```

Although this is a perfectly legitimate match, it is unnecessary as it is inferred by the fact that both Assembly_1 and Assembly_6 match Assembly_2. For this issue, I've tried querying the query, as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM Cloned_Query As a3
WHERE a3.Assembly NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT a1.Assembly AS Assembly
   FROM Cloned_Query as a1
   INNER JOIN Cloned_Query as a2 ON a1.Assembly=a2.CLONED_ASSEMBLY);
```

However this returns "No Current Record"?!  My theory was to to get a list of items found in both Assemble and CLONED_ASSEMBLY columns / fields and remove them from the Assembly column.

Again, any help very gratefully received!

Comment: Anybody any ideas....?!!