# How to remove reverse duplicates from a SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

**Context:** 
I have a select query where I have have link between devices. Some links have "reverse duplicates" that I would like to get rid of in the select query.

I already searched for similar questions especially this one : [Remove reverse duplicates from an SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13041802/remove-reverse-duplicates-from-an-sql-query)

But the solutions here works because it has only duplicates with an order but it isn't applicable in my case.

Here is a fiddle of the query with data examples to be easier to test

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/214e6/7

```sql
insert into link (ip_src, ip_dst) values ('192.168.0.1','192.168.0.2');
insert into link (ip_src, ip_dst) values ('192.168.0.1','192.168.0.3');
insert into link (ip_src, ip_dst) values ('192.168.0.5','192.168.0.4');
insert into link (ip_src, ip_dst) values ('192.168.0.7','192.168.0.8');
insert into link (ip_src, ip_dst) values ('192.168.0.8','192.168.0.7');
```

Desired result:

```
'192.168.0.1', '192.168.0.2'  
'192.168.0.1', '192.168.0.3'  
'192.168.0.5', '192.168.0.4'  
'192.168.0.7', '192.168.0.8'
```

Comment: Do you want to delete them from the table, or just suppress them in the result of a select query?

Comment: @wildplasser I just want to suprpess from the result. Using least and greatest function from the answer below works fine for me. Do you have another alternative ?

Comment: There is a good chance that LEAST() and GREATEST() are not sargable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about the ordering in the final result set, you can do:

```
select distinct least(ip_src, ip_dst) as ip_src, greatest(ip_src, ip_dst) as ip_dst
from link ;
```

Note: this can result in pairs not in the original table.

If you do care about ordering:

```
select ip_src, ip_dst
from link l
where ip_src <= ip_dst
union all
select ip_src, ip_dst
from link l
where ip_src > ip_dst and
      not exists (select 1 from link l2 where l2.ip_src = l.ip_dst and l2.ip_dst = l.ip_src);
```

Note:  This uses `union all`, so it does not remove duplicates.  You can use `union` to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM link l
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * from link nx 
          -- The condition below is true for both the twins
        WHERE nx.ip_src = l.ip_dst AND nx.ip_dst = l.ip_src
          -- this is true for only one of the twins
        AND nx.ip_src < nx.ip_dst
        );
```