# How to remove mirror results in PosgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, left-join

I couldn't figure out how to remove mirror results like this:

```
select
b.column1 as result1,
c.column2 as result2
from table a
left join table b on a.column1 = b.column1
left join table c on a.column2 = c.column1;
```

The results I get are the following:

```
result1|results2
b1     |b22
b5     |b66
b74    |b31
......
b22    |b1
b66    |b5
b31    |b74
```

How could I get only the first combination - if there is a combination b1-b22, I don't need b22-b1.

I've tried which distinct on the sum of b.column1 and c.column1 - I casted them to int and it works, but I don't believe it's the best way since there could be duplicated sums coming from different combinations and I'll lose some data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove reverse duplicates from an SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13041802/remove-reverse-duplicates-from-an-sql-query)

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit tricky if you don't have *all* combinations.  Your sample results do not have `null`, so I will change the `join`s to `inner join`s and then use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (least(b.column1, c.column2), greatest(b.column1, c.column2))
       b.column1 as result1, c.column2 as result2
from table a join
     table b
     on a.column1 = b.column1 join
     table c
     on a.column2 = c.column1
order by least(b.column1, c.column2), greatest(b.column1, c.column2);
```

Actually as your query is phrased, the `join`s don't seem needed at all.  So you might consider:

```
select distinct on (least(a.column1, a.column2), greatest(a.column1, a.column2))
       a.column1 as result1, a.column2 as result2
from table a
order by least(a.column1, a.column2), greatest(a.column1, a.column2);
```

Answer (score 1):

One method is to add an inequality condition in the last `join`:

```
select
    b.column1 as result1,
    c.column2 as result2
from table a
left join table b on a.column1 = b.column1
left join table c on a.column2 = c.column1 and b.column1 < c.column2
```

Answer (score 0):

"Remove mirror results" that sounds like you are for delete. This seems best addressed with a Exists clause:

```
delete from rtab r1
 where r1.result1 > r1.result2 
   and exists (select null 
                 from rtab r2
                where r1.result1 = r2.result2
                  and r1.result2 = r2.result1
               );
```